# VirtualBox machine - Set to access LAN only

Tags: virtualbox, lan

I've got a VirtualBox machine set up and it runs fine. But I want to limit it's network access to only computers on my LAN (192.168.2.x). I do not want it to have any type of incoming or outgoing access to the internet at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the Default Gateway in it's IP settings. Or modify the operating systems hosts file.

If your really serious about blocking it though you should block it via a firewall.